# Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "text: function(){return 'selection is: '+val }" Message: val is not defined

Tags: oracle-jet

> VM11347:3 Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: Unable to process
>   binding "text: function(){return 'selection is: '+val }" Message: val
>   is not defined

```
employee.js

define(['ojs/ojcore','knockout'],
function(oj,ko)
{  
  function AboutViewModel()
  {
      var self=this;
      self.val= ko.observable('nothing selected');
       document.getElementById('globalBody').addEventListener('selectionUpdate',selectionHandler,false);

       function selectionHandler(event)
       {
            self.val(event.detail.data);

       }

  }
});


employee.html

<div class="oj-hybrid-padding"> 
<h1>Employee Content</h1>
<div>
    <oj-bind-text value="[['selection is: '+val]]"></oj-bind-text>
    <h2> <input data-bind="value:val"></input></h2>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have defined AboutViewModel, but have not returned anything from your define block. Add this after your AboutViewModel function ends:

```
return new AboutViewModel();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
employee.js


   function selectionHandler(event)
   {
        self.val('selection is: '+event.detail.data);

   }
```

employee.html

```
<oj-bind-text value="[[$data.val]]"></oj-bind-text>
<h2> <input data-bind="value:val"></input></h2>
```

Hi,

You cannot both hardcode and return values in same jet. For that you can define that while setting value in js itself.